# Make the amount of queries constant with many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an entity which has 2 many-to-many relationships:
There is `Product`, which can have many categories and many tags. A `Tag` or a `Category`can also have many products.
The schema right now is:

```
products
-------------
product_id
name

categories
-------------
category_id
name

tags
-------------
tag_id
name

products_categories
-------------
product_id
category_id

products_tags
-------------
product_id
tag_id
```

I need to display in a single page a list of products with all their tags and categories.
The problem is that the number of queries I'm executing is `2n + 1` where n is the number of products listed in the page. 
Basically first I'm doing:

```
select product_id, name from products
```

Then in a loop in my application I do these queries (in pseudo code):

```
tags = []
categories = []
for each product
    tags[product_id] = select t.tag_id, t.name 
                       from products_tags as pt 
                       join tags t 
                           on pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
                       where pt.product_id = {product_id}

    categories[product_id] = select c.category_id, c.name 
                             from products_categories as pc 
                             join categories c 
                                 on pc.category = c.category_id
                             where pc.product_id = {product_id}
end for each
```

**Is there a good approach to make the number of executed queries independent of the number of records queried?**

**Edit**
For each product I need to display data in this format:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| Product name: A good smartphone                     |
| Categories: Tech, Smartphone                        |
| Tags: smartphone, some-smartphone-brand, 4g         |
|                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Edit your question and show what you want to display on each page, in a tabular format (what SQL queries produce).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (it uses a join with tags and categories in turn and differentiates them by a column table_type):

```
select *, 'CAT' as table_type
from products p left join products_categories pc left join categories c  
ON p.product_id = pc.product_id and pc.category_id = c.category_id
UNION ALL
select *, 'TAG' as table_type
from products p left join products_tags pt left join tags t  
ON p.product_id = pt.product_id and pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
order by p.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single query to get all information from database and at your application level structure your data as per your needs, Below query will return each product multiple times but with different tag/ category.

```
select p.product_id, p.name, t.tag_id, t.name tag_name, c.category_id, c.cat_name 
from product p
join products_tags as pt on pt.product_id = p.product_id
join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
join products_categories as pc on pc.product_id = p.product_id
join categories c on pc.category = c.category_id
order by p.product_id
```

Pseudo code

---

```
products = []
tags = []
categories = []
var productObj= {};
var product_id =false;
for each product
    /**
    * If product_id != product.id from loop iteration it means this is different product from previous iteration, Push this product object in `products[]`
    */
    if(product.id != product_id){
        products[product.id] = product;
        product_id = product.id;
    }
    /** you can put additional check here before insert in array if value is not present  `products[product.id][tags]` */
    products[product.id][tags][] = tag_name;

    /** you can put additional check here before insert in array if value is not present  `products[product.id][categories]` */ 
    products[product.id][categories][]= cat_name;
end for each
```

Sample object/ data structure for products

```
[ 
    1 => [
    name => A good smartphone,
    categories => [Tech, Smartphone],
    tags => [smartphone, some-smartphone-brand, 4g]
    ],  
    2 => [
    name: Another product,
    categories => [Cat1, Cat2],
    tags => [Tag1, Tag2, .....]
    ],
.....
]
```